# I've bought Mountain Lion, but where can I download it now?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

With the release of Mavericks, Mountain Lion seems to have disappeared from the AppStore. At least I could not find anything.

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23655153#23655153):

> It's still possible to buy OS X Mountain Lion in the Apple Online
>   Store > http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion

I have no intention of buying it again, so does anybody know a way to download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X Mountain Lion should still be listed in list of purchased applications in the OS X App Store application. You can download it from there.