# My mac came with Mountain Lion. I upgraded to mavericks - and now I can't find mountain lion download

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop, install

According to [I've bought Mountain Lion, but where can I download it now?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110045/ive-bought-mountain-lion-but-where-can-i-download-it-now) it should be in my purchase tab, but it isn't. ("option" does not help, it just lets you redownload if it is already in the list - which it isn't)

I would like an installable version of Mountain Lion to run inside parallels for testing software I develop against 10.8 (and potentially also 10.7, but let's stick to 10.8 for now).

How can I get an installer for older versions?

---

edit: found a way (for some reason site won't let me post this as an answer)

Use "Internet Recovery" (option-R during boot), and install Mountain Lion into an external USB drive. Then get parallels to import that. Awkward, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason which remains unexplained, the App Store 'Hides' the Mountain Lion purchase once Mavericks has been downloaded. The Lion purchase remains visible, but Mountain Lion becomes 'Hidden.'

Fire up **App Store** and go to **Purchases**. Now go to the **Store** menu and select **View my Account** - enter your password when asked. Go to the 2nd Section **iTunes in the Cloud** and click on **Manage** - You'll find **Mountain Lion** in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You might just download a torrent for Mountain Lion. OS X doesn't have any copy protection. You can create a VM from the dmg included with the installer application (`Install OS X Mountain Lion.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg`), so don't download any modified ISOs meant for PCs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want any hacker trojan installed in them (I want only Apple/NSA endorsed ones :) ). Is there a way to download it from Apple?